# export an android compound view as library

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to export my compound view as a library for reusing. I do it as follow:
Right Click on project> Properties > Android > And check Is Library

And copy exported jar file to a new project and add it to the library, Now when I want to run my project eclipes throws an error:

[2014-10-11 11:31:18 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim;
[2014-10-11 11:31:18 - khonemojaradi] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim;

According to error I know that I have same libraries that are there in my compound view and new project, But how can I fix it? I've done searches on stackoverflow and Google but I could not solve my problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should do two things:

1. Change the package route for your component because you may are having a conflict with other component of AppCompat 7
2. Don't copy the jar. Import your project as a Android Project. It is: in the target project, where you want to use your component, add your library project from:

   Right Click on project> Properties > Android > Add project (below Check project as Library, that should be unchecked).

If you have imported your library project, it should appear there.

Good luck buddy!

Comment: In case one, I don't understand your mean of change package rout :( But I do second case and solved my problem, Thanks. And there is an issue may that I don't want to share my source with other people. Whether in this case should to copy the jar file?

Comment: If you dont want to share your code maybe you should investigate techs like gradle or maven to build Android projects... but I'm not an expert with it...sorry. Please, if it is the correct answer mark it with the tick !! Good luck;)